# Calculating Average in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following csv files
File Genre_all.xlsx

```
A                            B  

Action|Adventure|Horror      4.8  
Action|Music                 7.2  
Horror|Adventure             5.6
```

Now, I need a file as follows
File Genre_avg.xlsx

```
A               B  
Action          6  
Adventure       5.2  
Horror          5.2  
Music           7.2
```

The column B is the average of the scores corresponding to the Genre.
Eg. For Action : (4.8+7.2)/2 = 6
What command should I use to get the following output?

Comment: You didn't include whatever output you want. In addition it doesn't look like you have actual CSV files but rather excel files as indicated by the name. You should either think about normalizing the first file or you would need to come up with a way to count the instances of a genre and sum the lines accordingly.

Comment: This is easily answered with a quick google. You've not shown any evidence of trying to find the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the first table as `sheet1` and the second as `sheet2`, cell B2 in `sheet2` could be

```
=AVERAGEIF(sheet1!A:A;"*" & A2 & "*";sheet1!B:B)
```

and so on.

Comment: =AVERAGEIF(sheet1!A:A,"*" & A2 & "*",sheet1!B:B)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using PowerQuery.

Split the first column and then unpivot the 1st 3 resulting columns. You would need to then group on Value

```
Value   Average
Action  6
Adventure   5.2
Horror  5.2
Music   7.2
```

You generally use PowerQuery with point and click but the resulting M code is:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type number}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type","Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv),{"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Value", "Column2"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns", {"Value"}, {{"Average", each List.Average([Column2]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

If you have Excel 2010 or 2013, PowerQuery is a free addin. Excel 2016 has it built in.

Comment: What about Excel 2007?

Comment: No, afraid not. Not too surprising really since that is at least 10 years old.

Comment: If you have an Office 365 license you may have a PowerBI std license and PowerBI desktop should also do it as it is basically PowerQuery without the Excel wrapper.